# Recursively import all interface implementations and instantiate them in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm building a script runner, so it's easy to reuse script code, but I want to make it easy for folks to add more scripts without having to change the `run-script.py` method. Ideally, I'd like to be able to call `run-scripts.py <ClassName>` and have it execute the interface in the class. Right now I'm testing the import functionality so if I run `run-script.py list`, it will list out all of the implementations of a base class interface and run a function on it.

My folder layout looks like this:

```
run-script.py
|- a
   |- script-a.py
   |- script-ab.py
|- b
   |- script-b.py
   |- ...
|- ...
```

I'm leveraging an abstract base class to define the interface contract, like this:

```py
class ScriptRunnerBaseClass(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    @abstractmethod
    def run(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def description(self):
        pass
```

And then doing an implementation like this:

```py
class AppStats(ScriptRunnerBaseClass, metaclass=ABCMeta):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def description(self):
        return "Here is my description!"

    def run(self):
        self.do_things()
```

In my `run-script.py` entrypoint, I'm currently trying to list out the description implementations of all of the implementations of the abstract base class. I found an [article on dynamic imports](https://www.bnmetrics.com/blog/dynamic-import-in-python3), and this is what I have so far.

```py
import argparse
import gc
import importlib
import inspect
import pkgutil
import sys
from inspect import isclass
from pathlib import Path

from cloudfoundry.runner import ScriptRunnerBaseClass


class ScriptLoader(object):
    ignored_locations = ["venv"]

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def load_all():
        for (_, name, _) in pkgutil.iter_modules([Path(__file__).parent]):
            imported_module = importlib.import_module(name, package=__name__)
            for i in dir(imported_module):
                attribute = getattr(imported_module, i)
                if inspect.isclass(attribute) and issubclass(attribute, ScriptRunnerBaseClass):
                    setattr(sys.modules[__name__], name, attribute)


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Run a script against Cloud Foundry!")
    parser.add_argument("list", help="List all available cf scripts.")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    ScriptLoader.load_all()

    if args.list:
        print_scripts()


def print_scripts():
    for obj in gc.get_objects():
        if isclass(obj):
            if issubclass(ScriptRunnerBaseClass, obj):
                # AppStats: Here is my description!
                print("{0}: {1}".format(obj.__name__, obj().description()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have verified the modules are loaded via a REPL, so I know the `ScriptLoader.load_all()` functionality is doing what I want it to do. When I run it, I get a `TypeError` I'm not 100% sure I understand:

```sh
✗ python3 run-script.py list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run-script.py", line 50, in <module>
    main()
  File "run-script.py", line 39, in main
    print_scripts()
  File "run-script.py", line 46, in print_scripts
    print("{0}: {1}".format(obj.__name__, obj().description()))
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Hashable with abstract methods __hash__
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I achieve the desired result of loading all the interface implementations and then calling methods on them?

Comment: Did you really intend to test ``issubclass(ScriptRunnerBaseClass, obj)``, instead of ``issubclass(obj, ScriptRunnerBaseClass)``? Your test will give you (abstract) *base* classes of ``ScriptRunnerBaseClass``, not (abstract) *child* classes. Notably, ``ScriptRunnerBaseClass`` satisfies a number of purely abstract classes, such as ``Hashable``.

Comment: Oh, I totally did not mean to do that. Should I edit my question or leave it?

Comment: If this is unintentional, it is likely the source of your error.

Comment: Well, I fixed it and it gave me a different error, so I think I'll continue to debug it and see what I find. Thanks @MisterMiyagi for pointing it out, though. :)